# Just doubled up on gold Steward badges... badging bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have, for some time now, had all 6 gold Steward badges for 1000 reviews of each type.  These badges explicitly say they are awarded once per review type only.  (And I haven't made 2000 reviews of all 6 types, even if they did say "once per every 1000 reviews".)

Well, today I was just awarded 6 more steward badges:

[image]

So now I have 12 gold Steward badges total.

[image]

Not that I don't appreciate the extra recognition, but the extra badges seem to be an error.
Anyone know why I got them?

Comment: It just happened to me too. I need a Covid vaccine, but instead I got gold badges.

Comment: Happened to me too and now it's been taken back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules are being changed; you're getting one Steward badge for every 1,000 reviews in a queue. See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1201991_360194) by Stack Exchange staff member @animuson:

> There's supposedly an announcement about review updates coming out today, if it hasn't been published somewhere yet. Seems the code is getting ahead of itself.

However, there seems to be a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360194/steward-badges-being-re-awarded-suddenly#comment1202005_360194), so you might lose some of them shortly:

> This is my bug, caused by a temporary issue with and old batch job running after a migration took place. I have a fix I can roll out in a few.

Comment: If there really is a change then I think someone should change the copy where it says "This bad is awarded once per review type."

Comment: @Robusto that's [in the works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360204/295232)

Comment: I guess someone put Descarte before the hearse.